# Dispalying a base64 string as an image vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am getting an image as base64 string from backend server. i would like to convert it into an image and display the same. I have tried the following:

Inside JS

```
let previewLogo2 = new Image();
previewLogo2.src = `data:image/png;base64,${fileList[i].file}`;
```

Inside template

```
<b-img :src="previewLogo2" class="certificate-logo-size logo2 pt-2"></b-img>
```

I am using bootstrap vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by binding to previewLogo2.src instaed of previewLogo2

Inside JS

```
let previewLogo2 = new Image();
previewLogo2.src = `data:image/png;base64,${fileList[i].file}`;
```

Inside Template

```
<b-img :src="previewLogo2.src" class="certificate-logo-size logo2 pt-2"></b-img>
```

Comment: You don't need to create an `Image` here. Just use a string instead.

Comment: using a string didnt work for me. the image is not getting displayed.

Comment: There's likely a different issue that prevents the image from displaying, but I'd have to see what you actually tried. `new Image().src` itself is a string, and you're not using `Image` in any way, so it's not really needed.